# How do I calculate percentage change in an Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have 2 cells in Excel and I'm trying to find a formula to display the percentage change between them.

For example:

- If B2=100 and B3=102, the result should be: +2%
- If B2=103 and B3=100, the result should be: -3%

What formula can I use to calculate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=B3/B2-1` will do the job.

In case your number would be in percent and you'd want the change in %pts, this would be the formula `=B3-B2` (though I don't think you're looking for that one)

Answer (score 1):

```
=(B3/B2)-1
```

Set 'result' format to Percentage and you're all set!